# ndiff - PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, diff, nmap

I have a problem with Ndiff, I can't execute it. (Nmap works perfect)

So I try to use ndiff and get this error message:

```
Could not import the ndiff module: 'No module named ndiff'.

I checked in these directories:

/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/ndiff
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

If you installed Ndiff in another directory, you may have to add the
modules directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.
```

So I search for the path of ndiff and export it to PYTHONPATH. But it doesn't work out, what I am doing wrong?

```
which ndiff
/usr/local/bin/ndiff
```

---

I re-install ndiff and nmap with homebrew and know I get this message, after I try to execute this code

```
$ ndiff firstScan.xml secondScann.xml > diffScan

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ndiff", line 84, in <module>
    sys.excepthook = ndiff.excepthook
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'excepthook'
```

Comment: know I have this problem: usr/bin/awk: can't open file ./share/lib/ndiff/ndiff-2.00/ndiff.awk
 source line number 1 source file ./share/lib/ndiff/ndiff-2.00/ndiff.awk
 context is
  >>>  <<<

Comment: ndiff firstScan.xml secondScann.xml > diffScan is this one

Comment: Most likely, your `PYTHONPATH` needs to include `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (you can see it's not searched for, thus not included). `ndiff` is probably just wrapper program around a Python module, and without the correct `PYTHONPATH`, it can't found that module.

Comment: Btw, don't use the symlink @PadraicCunningham suggests; it doesn't help, except for convoluting things. I think this is causing the second error, since `/usr/local/bin/ndiff` will now see an `ndiff.py` file in your current directory as the ndiff module (which, of course, it is not). If you have that `ndiff.py` file, remove it.

Comment: @Evert, so `Could not import the ndiff module: 'No module named ndiff'.` comes from bash yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, because the `ndiff` command is a Python script without the `.py` extension, which apparently tries to import a module called `ndiff`. Once it fails that, it issues the help text "I checked in these directories: .... If you installed Ndiff in another directory, you may have to add the
modules directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable."

Comment: For the record, here is that ndiff script: https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/ndiff/scripts/ndiff

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Probably the ndiff version you're looking at is an older version; I have an older version on my system as well. In a newer version, they moved most of the code into a separate module. Compare [this older version](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/ndiff/ndiff?p=32000) to [this newer version](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/ndiff/scripts/ndiff). The latter, newer version, also explains the last error the OP saw: the line `sys.excepthook = ndiff.excepthook` exists in the newer script, not in the older script. There's also a note in the nmap changelog on this for nmap version 6.47.

Comment: Also: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/commit/1e6db2b22c5c5ebe44e9974e8c794c7804089383 makes it more clear that things changed recently.

Comment: first - sry for my late response and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you're trying to run `/usr/local/bin/ndiff`, is a Python script in disguise (that is, it doesn't have the `.py` extension).

Somewhere at the top of that script, it tries to import the `ndiff` module itself:

```
import ndiff
```

which, seen the path `/usr/local/`, is probably installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`(*). You need to add this path to your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Now, the script can pick up the module, and happily continue.

(*) it may get installed somewhere else, in which case you'll have to locate it manually. You could try something like `find /usr/local -name ndiff.py` to see where it is installed.

---

The second error, after your re-install, could be caused by a loose `ndiff.py` somewhere in your current working directory. In that case, `/usr/local/bin/ndiff` will try to import that file, and think it's the actual `ndiff` module. Since it's not, it will fail when it tries to access some of the modules attributes like `ndiff.excepthook`, which that loose `ndiff.py` doesn't have. Remove the loose file and you should be good to go.

Comment: perfect :) it works :) thank you so much. the file was in python2.6

Comment: @Loretta You mean inside the `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`? Because that seems a bit odd, given that the error messages in your question show Python 2.7 there. If it works, don't change it, but at some point, you may consider to do `brew update` and then `brew upgrade`.

Comment: yes, I mean this. no error messages it works perfect. And thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not necessary to change the PYTHONPTH environment variable, what happens is that the ndiff script is pointing either to a wrong path or to a wrong/non-existent file. 
Just edit the ndiff script (passed as a binary) located likely in /usr/bin/ndiff:

```
# sudo vi /usr/bin/ndiff
```

and locate the line: INSTALL_LIB = '...

It should read the full path to your python site-packages directory, for example:
INSTALL_LIB = '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'

Seek for a file named ndiff.py in there:

```
# sudo find /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages -name ndiff.py
```

If there is none present, you must create it and paste all the content present here in it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmap/nmap/master/ndiff/ndiff.py

It should all work then.